# comparing 2 set of dataset with looping errors

Tags: .net, vb.net

i got 2 set of dataset which manage to stored data_Before and data_after

what i trying to do in my if statement below is to check is the column for my data_after belong to the boolean column? if yes, i will not display the data if there are 1

but there are problem existing here, i got no idea why it loop for at least 20time whenever there are only 1 different, it repeated the differentiation for multiple time

```
For nDsAf_Col As Integer = 0 To pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim sChkColName As String =    pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Columns(nDsAf_Col).ColumnName
                    Dim sChkRowData As String = pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Rows(nDsAf_Rows)(sColTableKey).ToString
```

//problem occurs here!

```
                      If sChkColName Is sColTableKey AndAlso sChkRowData IsNot "1" Then
                        '13)Loop pDsAf_Columns, return result as null to something
                        For nTempColAf As Integer = 0 To pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Columns.Count - 1
                            Dim sCol As String = pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Columns(nTempColAf).ColumnName
                            Dim sB4 As String = reportNullData
                            Dim sAf As String = pDsAf.Tables(nDsB4_Tables).Rows(nDsAf_Rows)(nTempColAf).ToString
```

if my data_before is different with my data_after, append the string

```
                            If sB4 <> sAf Then
                                returnString += sCol + reportColNameSeperator + sB4 + reportDiffSeparator + sAf + reportColSeperator + Environment.NewLine
                            End If

                        Next
                    End If

                Next
```

**my data_B4**

---

UID            |USER_ACTION          |TableKey

---

1              |EAT                  |0

---

**my data after**

---

UID            |USER_ACTION          |TableKey

---

1              |EAT                  |1

---

2              |Play                 |0

---

**Example data**

my expected result is the table key is not 1 then display the row data

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

but the result that visual studio gave to me is (repeated for dont know how many time)

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

UID: NULL > 2

USER_ACTION: NULL > Play

Comment: Where are you declaring sColTableKey and setting its value?  What type is it?

Comment: is a string type,   Dim sColTableKey As String = "TableKey"

Comment: Does it repeat this for every row?  Have you tried evaluating sChkRowData as a boolean instead of looking for a string value in that column?

Comment: wait i upload the result =)

Comment: I can't see here where you're looping over the rows, only over the columns.

Comment: i think i will find a better way to post my whole function, it was too long, lets me think is that any short cut for me to describe it ~

Answer (score 0):

please check this is ok that you are giving right "Table Name OR Table Index" at highlighted place, what i think there should be the table name exists in "pDsAf" NOT of "nDsB4_Tables"

For nDsAf_Col As Integer = 0 To pDsAf.Tables(**nDsB4_Tables**).Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim sChkColName As String =    pDsAf.Tables(**nDsB4_Tables**).Columns(nDsAf_Col).ColumnName
                    Dim sChkRowData As String = pDsAf.Tables(**nDsB4_Tables**).Rows(nDsAf_Rows)(sColTableKey).ToString

Answer (score 0):

Or u may have mistake at nested loop

For nTempColAf As Integer = 0 To pDsAf.Tables(**nDsB4_Tables**).Columns.Count - 1

you should try to do folowing

```
for r=0 to 1stDS.rowcount
   for col=0 to 1stDS.col_Count
       //now place you condition here Like

       if (1stDS Row Or Column (whatever you want)==2ndDS Row Or Column
         {
          //you code
         }
   Next
 Next
```